# Fixing an exit function with invalid input print statements reoccuring

Tags: python, function, loops, dictionary, exit-code

My code is running pretty smooth. I have some sentence structure I want to add to the game to make it more immersive. I forgot to add an exit to my game. i created an exit and it works, now when i type in any other command, even if it works, i get a print statement of invalid input. i have moved my exit and invalid statement around the codes but i cant seem to get past this. i left the invalid statement at the bottom of my code. i want to be able to type in other commands than 'exit' and not get the invalid print statement for instance, if i type 'go North' i do move to the next room but i get an output of "invalid input" before the print statements from the room. any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
 
# declaration
rooms = {
    'Town Square': {'North': 'Bookstore', 'South': 'Restaurant', 'East': 'Jeweler', 'West': 'Tailor', 'item': 'None'},
    'Tailor': {'East': 'Town Square', 'item': 'Suit'},
    'Restaurant': {'North': 'Town Square', 'East': 'Hair Dresser', 'item': 'Salad'},
    'Hair Dresser': {'West': 'Restaurant', 'item': 'Comb'},
    'Bookstore': {'South': 'Town Square', 'East': 'Shoemaker', 'item': 'Bible'},
    'Shoemaker': {'West': 'Bookstore', 'item': 'Shoes'},
    'Jeweler': {'North': 'Chapel', 'West': 'Town Square', 'item': 'Ring'},
    'Chapel': {'South': 'Jeweler', 'item': 'Wife'}
}
state = 'Town Square'


# function
def get_new_state(state, direction):
    new_state = state  # declaring
    for i in rooms:  # loop
        if i == state:  # if
            if direction in rooms[i]:  # if
                new_state = rooms[i][direction]  # assigning new_state
    return new_state  # return


# function
def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state]['item']  # returning Item value


# function
def show_instructions():
    # print a main menu and the commands
    print("Welcome to the Wedding Adventure!")
    print("Collect all 6 items before you reach the chapel, so you will not die of embarrassment when you get left at "
          "the altar")
    print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


show_instructions()  # calling function
inventory = []
while (1):  # gameplay loop
    print('You are in ', state)  # printing state
    print('Inventory:', inventory)  # printing inventory
    item = get_item(state)  # calling get_item function
    print('You see a', item)  # print
    print('------------------------------')
    if item == 'Wife':  # if
        if len(inventory) == 6:
            print('Congratulations! You have collected all the items and got married!')
            print('Thank you for playing the game!')
            exit(0)
        else:
            print('SLAP ... GAME OVER!')
            print('Thanks for playing! Hope you enjoyed it!')
            exit(0)
    direction = input('Enter your move: ')  # asking user
    if direction == 'go East' or direction == 'go West' or direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go South':  # if
        direction = direction[3:]
        new_state = get_new_state(state, direction)  # calling function
        if new_state == state:  # if
            print('The room has wall in that direction enter other direction!')  # print
        else:
            state = new_state  # changing state value to new_state
            print('Invalid input')
    elif direction == str('get ' + item):  # Obtain item
        if item in inventory:  # if item already present in inventory
            print('Item already taken go to another room!!')
        else:
            print(f"{item} retrieved!\n")
            inventory.append(item)  # appending
    if direction == 'exit':
        print('Thank you for playing')
        exit(0)
    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

My error looks like this

```
Enter your move: go North
Invalid input
Invalid input
You are in  Bookstore
Inventory: []
You see a Bible
------------------------------
Enter your move: exit
Thank you for playing
```

Comment: Change `if direction == 'exit':` to `elif direction == 'exit':`. Otherwise, the `else:` block is only connected to the last `if`, not the whole `if/elif` chain.

Comment: thank you for the advice. changing it to elif and removing line 65 solved my issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `if` in the line where you check for exit with `elif`.
The if-else structure means that the program only checks for 2 cases, meaning, every time the input is not exit it is invalid.

The `elif` expression in python means if all of the previous conditions were not true, then try this condition and so on..

By changing the `if` to `elif` your program won't move to the `else` block if any of the previous conditions (if the input is valid) was true.

```
while (1):  # gameplay loop
    ....
    direction = input('Enter your move: ')  # asking user
    if direction == 'go East' or direction == 'go West' or direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go South':  # if
        ....

    elif direction == str('get ' + item):  # Obtain item
        ....

    elif direction == 'exit':
        print('Thank you for playing')
        exit(0)

    else:
        print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: Thank you for the definition explanation. If statements make more sense now. I am still running into the same issue even when i change it to an elif statement. That's why i was wondering if one of these statements needs to be added in a different spot.

Comment: Enter your move: go North
Invalid input
You are in  Bookstore
Inventory: []
You see a Bible
------------------------------
Enter your move: go East
Invalid input
You are in  Shoemaker
Inventory: []
You see a Shoes
------------------------------
Enter your move: exit
Thank you for playing

Comment: Why is there a print of invalid input in line 65?

Comment: Can you please post all of your output, it is hard to tell why you got invalid input, but in my suspicion you switched states and you got `Invalid input` because of the print in line 65..

Comment: there it is! line 65 is my issue. After i deleted line 65 and changed the elif it runs the way i want! i think when i was moving those codes around i forgot to delete line 65. Thank you so much for the help!